# Understanding Celery Flower Display

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, flower

What does it mean when Celery flower shows a task as **N/A** in the active column? (screenshot 01 -task data_01 in Active column)

Not sure if they are related but again on the same row of data_01, it shows a total of 263,497 received and 251,900 succeeded with no Failure or Retried. My understanding would be that the difference in received Vs. succeeded would mean there are still jobs in the queue? (screenshot 01)

Issue though is, when I interrogate rabbit-mq, the validate_data queue is empty so am note sure what that variance of about 11,000 is coming from (screenshot 02 & screenshot 03)

**Screenshot01**
[image: flower screenshot01]

**Screenshot02**
[image: rabbit-mq webpage screenshot02]

**Screenshot03**
[image: rabbit-mq console screenshot03]

Comment: The culprit here might be python memory leaks. Your processed and succeeded list are counting the number of objects that were pushed onto the Queue and then successfully popped off, but if you are popping off empty references after whatever action is done to them, that could account for your deficit. It's hard to really diagnose without seeing the code.

Comment: Hey, did you find out more about the issue? I am having the same issue and would be great if you shared your findings as an answer.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what does it mean when it shows 2 or 3 or any number >1 in active column?